# Android with Gradle and Proguard

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-library

I'm just created a new Android Library project using Gradle and would like the code to be optimized and obfuscated with via Proguard.

Here is the android portion the **build.gradle** file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

When I run the **gradle build** command from terminal it fails at **:library:proguardRelease** with the message:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':library:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
```

Does anybody know why this is?

Gradle 1.10
JVM 1.6.0_65
Progruard 4.10

Answer (score 5):

The following `build.gradle` file works for me with Proguard when executing `gradlew assembleRelease`.

Note it is set up to read the release keystore info from a config file (and I've included the debug key cert in the project, since its needed for Maps API v2 in debug mode), and passwords from the command line:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    if (project.hasProperty("secure.properties")
            && new File(project.property("secure.properties")).exists()) {

        Properties props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(file(project.property("secure.properties"))))

        signingConfigs {
            debug {
                storeFile file("gpstest.debug.keystore")
            }

            release {
                storeFile file(props['key.store'])
                keyAlias props['key.alias']
                storePassword "askmelater"
                keyPassword "askmelater"
            }
        }
    } else {
        signingConfigs {
            debug {
                storeFile file("gpstest.debug.keystore")
            }

            release {
                // Nothing here
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile 'proguard.cfg'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    } 
}

task askForPasswords << {
    // Must create String because System.readPassword() returns char[]
    // (and assigning that below fails silently)
    def storePw = new String(System.console().readPassword("\nKeystore password: "))
    def keyPw = new String(System.console().readPassword("Key password: "))

    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = storePw
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = keyPw
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
    if (theTask.name.equals("packageRelease")) {
        theTask.dependsOn "askForPasswords"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':ShowcaseViewLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'org.jraf:android-switch-backport:1.2'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.2.1'
}
```

Here are the instructions to set up the config files to read keystore info:

> To build a release build, you need to create a "gradle.properties" file that points to a "secure.properties" file, and a "secure.properties" file that points to your keystore and alias. The `gradlew assembleRelease` command will prompt for your keystore passphrase.
>
> The "gradle.properties" file is located in the GPSTest directory and has the contents:

```
secure.properties=<full_path_to_secure_properties_file>
```

> The "secure.properties" file (in the location specified in gradle.properties) has the contents:

```
key.store=<full_path_to_keystore_file>

key.alias=<key_alias_name>
```

> Note that the paths in these files always use the Unix path separator  `/`, even on Windows. If you use the Windows path separator `\` you will get the error `No value has been specified for property 'signingConfig.keyAlias'.`

Here's the path to the file/project on Github if you want to clone and test it yourself:
https://github.com/barbeau/gpstest/blob/master/GPSTest/build.gradle

`proguard.cfg` is also in the GPSTest subdirectory (same directory as `build.gradle`):
https://github.com/barbeau/gpstest/blob/master/GPSTest/proguard.cfg