# Android Studio proguardRelease FAILED due empty output jar library

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

I have imported a project from Eclipse into Android Studio 1.0.1 that consists in an Android Library Project (RuletaAfortunadaCore) and an Android Project (RuletaAfortunada), also have some third parties library dependencies. During the import everything seemed fine, but now when I try to build it I get this error message from Gradle:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ruletaAfortunadaCore:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
```

The whole output from the start of the building process:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :ruletaAfortunada:compileDebugSources, :facebookSDK:compileDebugSources, :ruletaAfortunadaCore:compileDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:facebookSDK:clean
:ruletaAfortunada:clean UP-TO-DATE
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:clean
:facebookSDK:compileLint
:facebookSDK:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:facebookSDK:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:facebookSDK:preBuild
:facebookSDK:preReleaseBuild
:facebookSDK:checkReleaseManifest
:facebookSDK:prepareReleaseDependencies
:facebookSDK:compileReleaseAidl
:facebookSDK:compileReleaseRenderscript
:facebookSDK:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:facebookSDK:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebookSDK:mergeReleaseAssets
:facebookSDK:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:facebookSDK:generateReleaseResources
:facebookSDK:packageReleaseResources
:facebookSDK:processReleaseManifest
:facebookSDK:processReleaseResources
:facebookSDK:generateReleaseSources
:facebookSDK:compileReleaseJava
:facebookSDK:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:facebookSDK:packageReleaseJar
:facebookSDK:compileReleaseNdk
:facebookSDK:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:facebookSDK:packageReleaseLocalJar
:facebookSDK:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:facebookSDK:bundleRelease
:ruletaAfortunada:preBuild
:ruletaAfortunada:preDebugBuild
:ruletaAfortunada:checkDebugManifest
:ruletaAfortunada:preReleaseBuild
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:compileLint
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:preBuild
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:preReleaseBuild
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:checkReleaseManifest
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:preDebugBuild
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:preDebugTestBuild
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:prepareRuletaAfortunadaFacebookSDKUnspecifiedLibrary
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:prepareReleaseDependencies
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:compileReleaseAidl
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:compileReleaseRenderscript
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:mergeReleaseAssets
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:generateReleaseResources
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:mergeReleaseResources
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:processReleaseManifest
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:processReleaseResources
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:generateReleaseSources
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:compileReleaseJava
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:extractReleaseAnnotations
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:compileReleaseNdk
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:packageReleaseResources
:ruletaAfortunadaCore:proguardRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ruletaAfortunadaCore:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
```

The contents of the build.gradle file for such library project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 13
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/chartboost.jar')
    compile files('libs/mint-4.0.7.jar')
}
```

**UPDATE**: I have realized that the Android Library Project named RuletaAfortunadaCore can be build as an standalone project or made as a module without problems at all. It only fails to build when building the whole RuletaAfortunada Android Project that uses it.

The build.gradle file for such Android Project is the default one created by Android Studio, I think, so has nothing interesting inside. Anyway, here it is, just in case:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is the settings.gradle:

```
include ':facebookSDK'
include ':ruletaAfortunadaCore'
include ':ruletaAfortunada'
```

And finally, just to have all of them, this is the facebookSDK module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 9
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 9
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.2.jar')
}
```

Comment: which version of Android Studio you have ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android with Gradle and Proguard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691678/android-with-gradle-and-proguard)

Comment: @shkschneider it is not because I got the same issue after upgrading  my AS (Android Studio)

Comment: @Fran can you show us some of your main `-keep` of your proguard file?

Comment: I don't think is duplicate: in the link you post, he is creating a new library directly in Android studio. In this case I have imported an Android Library that already exists and does work perfectly in Eclipse. So it is possible that, being the same error, the source of the problem and hence the solution, could be completely different.

Comment: I am using the last available Android Studio version, just installed today. JFTR: 1.0.1

Comment: The proguard-project.txt file is exactly the same than in the Eclipse project. I would take a look on it, anyway. Something specific to look for? Also, is there anyway to get more information from that error? you know, like changing some configuration in Android Studio so it passes some flag to Gradle so it is more verbose or whatever...

Comment: Can you provide a listing of the "build.gradle" file for the application and library modules.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm here confirming the same issue - some recent change in Android Studio?

Comment: @AndroidGuy I have added the contents of the build.gradle for this library project.

Comment: Also I have realized that the library project by itself builds as a module without problems, it only fails when I try to build the android project that depends on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by one guy which answer seem to have vanished now :-?, the solution for me has been to set minifyEnabled to false in the build.gradle of my Library Project. As far as I have it set as true for the Android Project itself, proguard will be executed anyway and the error have disappeared.

Comment: Here is the'vanishing answer' did : 

When Gradle build the library project, it ALWAYS build the Release variant.

The solution that worked for me is to not obfuscate the library in the library project ('minifyEnabled false'), and let the application project make the obfuscating.

Sadly, my answer (that you selected as a good answer) was deleted by a moderator, and I don't know why although I asked for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I've found some useful info here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0
One notable difference is that runProguard was changed to minifyEnabled.
However, after completing the steps from this migration topic, I still run into the same build error.

Comment: Not useful for me neither. Actually I have re imported the project from Eclipse to see if it works, since I had not made any changes to it yet, and same problem there.